# Exact criterion for implicit synchronization in CUDA

Tags: concurrency, cuda, language-lawyer, nvidia, gpgpu

The CUDA programming guide [says](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#implicit-synchronization) (Section 3.2.5.5.4; emphasis mine):

> #### Implicit Synchronization
>
> Two commands from different streams cannot run concurrently if any one of the following operations is *issued in-between them* by the host thread:
>
> - a page-locked host memory allocation,
> - a device memory allocation,
> - a device memory set,
> - a memory copy between two addresses to the same device memory,
> - any CUDA command to the NULL stream,
> - a switch between the L1/shared memory configurations described in Compute Capability 3.x and Compute Capability 7.x.

What do the phrases "in between them" and "issued in between them" mean, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly - the wording refers to the times at which the commands are scheduled, i.e. "if you scheduled some command C triggering implicit synchro after scheduling other things - everything you've scheduled before C will be executed first; then C will execute; then anything you've scheduled after C".

Comment: The way I understand it is on its simple form: If you do `asyncfun(stream1); syncfun(); asyncfun(stream2);` the two asyncs will not be concurrent. So yes, what you said. Its a weird wording, but basically saying the simplest thing in parallel computing: if you put a wall, its a wall. Perhaps only worded that way to allow the list to proceed the docs.